# Unwated consistency of solver results with pyomo over several runs

Tags: python-3.x, mathematical-optimization, pyomo, ipopt

I'm using pyomo 6.6.4 and several solvers (Ipopt, Bonmin, Cbc,...) to solve different relatively complicated models (MINLP in general). Since my models have known infeasibility points I am solving them using several solvers or heuristics. In order to evaluate the quality of the results between different solvers or self defined solving heuristics I'm trying to build a solver comparison tool and noticed that when solving several time a model with a solver in a loop I'm always getting the same results whereas when using single runs, the results often differ.

I have tried to use different solver instances, model instances, to change the randomness generation seeds between iterations (for solvers which allow it) but nothing seems to do the trick. Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you want. I think reproducibility is a good thing, and high-end solvers are designed to make runs as reproducible as possible. You seem to want different solution paths for different runs with the same data. Some MIP solvers have a **seed** option to achieve that.

Comment: I know that the solver is not always computing the optimal solution and I know why. What I want is to evaluate how often the solution in not optimal or if it even succeeds, but if I solve the model several times inside a loop I'm always getting the same result while single runs give me different results.

Comment: When using a loop, subsequent solves may use the optimal values of a previous solve as an initial point.